# VueJS - reference a prop in a component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

Looking to implement a component and on a click event I want to reference a prop in a method. A simple example:

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <span>Hi!</span>
    <button
      class="action"
      @click.stop="clicked"
    >{{notificationTitle}}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Toastification',
  props: {
    notificationTitle: {
      type: String,
    },
    notificationID: {
      type: String,
    }

  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      this.$emit('eventName', this.notificationID)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This may not be the production version, it is just an example. I can access a prop in the Template part using {{}}, but in the method using this.notificationID fails - how do I correctly reference notificationID?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, when I read through the code, so obvious! Pass in the prop to the method call:

```js
 @click.stop="clicked(notificationSetID)"


then:
clicked(notificationSetID) {
    console.log(notificationSetID)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks perfect and it should work. Here, I just creating a working Demo. Please have a look and let me know if you faced any challenge.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['notificationtitle', 'notificationid'],
  template: `<div class="container">
    <span>Hi!</span>
    <button
      class="action"
      @click.stop="clicked"
    >{{ notificationtitle }}</button>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      console.log(this.notificationid);
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child notificationTitle="Hello Vue !" notificationID="1">
  </child>
</div>
```